# Detecting first inner black circle and making a contour: openCV and Python

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, contour, image-editing

I want to detect the first inner black circle from the white solid using OpenCV and Python.

[image: The circle is shown with arrow]

I have tried thresholding but it is not working properly.

```
imporrt cv2

guass_kernal = 5
eroded_kernal = (3, 3)
canny_low_limit = 12
canny_up_limit = 20
eroded_iteration = 3

def eroded_image(self, canny_image):
        dilated = cv2.dilate(canny_image, (self.eroded_kernal), iterations=self.eroded_iteration)
        eroded = cv2.erode(dilated, self.eroded_kernal, iterations=self.eroded_iteration)

        thresh = cv2.adaptiveThreshold(eroded, 255, cv2.ADAPTIVE_THRESH_GAUSSIAN_C, cv2.THRESH_BINARY_INV, 3, 2)
        return thresh

image = cv2.imread('image231.jpg', cv2.IMREAD_COLOR)
RGB_image = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
gray_image = cv2.cvtColor(RGB_image, cv2.COLOR_RGB2GRAY) #gray image

blur_image = cv2.GaussianBlur(gray_image, (guass_kernal, guass_kernal), 5)
canny_image = cv2.Canny(blur_image, canny_low_limit, canny_up_limit, None, 3)
masked_image = eroded_image(canny_image)


contours, heirarchy = cv2.findContours(masked_image, cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
cv2.drawContours(image, contours, -1, (255, 0, 255), 5)
```

Please help me refine the code and detect the inner circle properly.

Comment: Don't use canny or blur.  Simply threshold an then use HoughCircles.

Comment: I am not clear on which circle you want. Is it the outside of the white inner circle or the outer circle from the black annulus?

Comment: Or are you asking about the first ring of the diffraction pattern that is between the white and the black annulus?

Comment: Hi, thankyou for your reply. i have added another image to show which circle i am talking about. It is the first black circle line that comes when you move outside from the center of the solid white circle and hit the black boundary.

Comment: Is that not just the circumference of the white inner circle? If you want the black line, then threshold on the white inner circle and dilate the amount that the first black ring is outside the white. Then use HoughCircle or minEnclosingCircle to get the circle and redraw on a black background.

Comment: Hi, could you please help me with some code to do the above process pleasee.

Comment: [crosspost](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/266159): https://forum.opencv.org/t/detecting-first-inner-black-circle-and-making-a-contour/16687